# How to display value in View global text field if another field has specific value

Tags: views

In my scenario I'm trying to display a flag (Font Awesome icon) in Views Global Text Field if another field in the same row of a type "Date" has a value of, say, a week from now.
I tried [Views Table Highlighter](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_table_highlighter) but it has some bugs with filters I'm using, so I thought that using the above approach would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [views conditional module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional).

> Views Conditional is a simple module that allows you to define conditionals (if xxx then yyy)
>   with fields in views