# Output based on taxonomy term value, also if a field has value

Tags: 7, views, theming, taxonomy-terms

I have a View which I need to alter the output depending on whether the field (taxonomy term) has a certain value. If the value of the taxonomy field is "Yes", I want to add a surrounding  to the view so that it links to a details page. If the value is "No", I want to output without the surrounding  so there isn't a link to a details page as not all of the nodes in the view will have a details page.

Normally in a node template file I'd use "if(!empty($node->field_subtitle['und'][0]['value'])) {" etc but that doesn't work in Views.

Any ideas guys? I've looked through many articles online but can't figure it out.

Kind regards
Liam

Comment: Here is an approach by using a [module](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215097/how-to-display-value-in-view-global-text-field-if-another-field-has-specific-val/216006#216006). If you are interesting in a code solution try to implement [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view/7.x-3.x) preprocess function